# D3 refresh axes labels

Tags: refresh, axis, d3.js

I have a graph that I show two sets of data in it.  The user can hit a button to flip to another set of data.  The problem is the axes aren't the same, but when I want to update the ticks I instead just layer on top another axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/scottieb/VjHd6/

The key bit is at the end:

```
 vis.selectAll("axis").remove();

    vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (h - margin ) + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .tickFormat(formatCurrency)
         );
```

I've tried selectAll("g").remove(), but that prevents laying down the next axis.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, needed to redefine the scale and call a transition rather than just build a whole new axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/scottieb/JwaaV/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your selector is not correct. Instead of selecting "axis", you should select ".axis" since you are appending a "g" node with a class.